# Admin Dashboard taking 3 minutes to load after login in Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3, performance

I am noticing very slow initial load of Admin Dashboard (Magento 2.3.4) after the user logs in to admin area. If you refresh the screen after log in, then everything is working normal, also store front has no performance issues (admin also working normally after initial 3 minute wait after you click Login).

I have observed processes on the server and there doesn't seem anything unusual that would cause high load. The URL of the request that is taking 3 minutes is `/adminurl/admin/dashboard/index/key/..../` but as mentioned before, if I refresh the page, the same URL takes only 0.6s and all other parts of this Magento has normal response times, it's just this first load after the login.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the exact same thing.

"On my local install (WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04, Magento 2.3.4) if I don't use my admin for many hours, and I try to log back in, the login can take 2-3 minutes to authenticate. But after that first long delay, I'm able to work quickly, and even re-login quickly."

Comment: In my case the issue went away by itself. I suppose there is some remote call going on after login and remote service was not responsive. Issue was present for some days and after that it didn't repeat so I didn't investigate,